# Namespaces just seem to be making things more complicated. Am I missing something?

Tags: php, namespace

Now that I am using namespaces in my php files which match the file's path, I have to append a namespace to pretty much every class instantiation. The namespaces definitely help my autoloader find files, but the code is becomming harder to read/write. aren't namespaces supposed to simplify my code? why is it making things more complicated? Am I using it wrong? Not sure I see how using a namespace is much better than having super long class names...

example:

file: /root_path/init.php

```
<?php
    namespace root_path;
    $foo = new \sub_path\bar();
?>
```

file: /root_path/sub_path/bar.php

```
<?php
    namespace root_path\sub_path;
    class bar {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Never had a particular need for them myself.  You dont HAVE to use them if you dont think they are helping.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I am using namespaces primarily for the class autoloader. Many classes are found in subfolders, and namespaces seemed the easiest way for the autoloader to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using it right, but you might not have a need for it.

Namespacing allows you to use function and symbol names without worrying about whether a third-party library declares the same thing (which would cause a fatal error in PHP). You can take comfort in knowing that, because you've namespaced everything, there's no chance for collision.

But if you're in a position where you're going to know and account for all possible symbols, you're not going to get a whole lot of value from namespaces. **Edit:** And as G3D mentions in the comments, your specific use case is covered by [PEAR's naming conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php).

However, relying on prefixes might not work as you'd expect if you start introducing a lot of unknowns.

This comes up in [Drupal](http://drupal.org): let's say you've created a module that's named **views**. Well, Drupal provides a hook system, so you can do things like implement the function `hook_foo()` by replacing `hook` with your module's name.

So now you have an implementation of a hook named `views_foo()`. That's all well and fine as long as you didn't need an internal function named `views_foo()`.

But let's say there's a new module that extends your module and names itself **views_awesome**. If `views_awesome` wants to implement `hook_foo()`, it'd create a new function named `views_awesome_foo()`.

Ah, but I didn't tell you about another hook already defined:`hook_awesome_foo()`. So, without namespacing, you have a collision: `views_awesome_foo()` can refer to `view_awesome`'s  implementation of `hook_foo` **or** `views`'s implementation of `hook_awesome_foo()`.

In this scenario, namespacing is really helpful. Instead of prefixing hook implementations, you can do:

```
\views\hook_foo()
\views_awesome\hook_foo()
```

and avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: I am using namespaces primarily for the class autoloader. Many classes are found in subfolders, and namespaces seemed the easiest way for the autoloader to find them.

Comment: You don't need namespaces for that, the Zend/Pear naming convention (what you using) allows that.

Comment: @G3D indeed, added that note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They do, in a way, but they are *critical* for long term code reuse. Otherwise you have to make sure that there are no variable namespace collisions, and that becomes extremely cumbersome.

Lack of namespaces has been a very big issue with php, especially given its very loose scoping.